# How can I sort my my first two columns A-Z?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to sort Columns that contain letters and numbers. I want to sort the Column A-Z, I've tried reading up on some functions and attempting to get it to sort however I'm getting this error:

```
Private Function Sort2()
    Set HSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Building Parts")
    HBLR = HSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Building Parts").Activate

    With Range(Columns("A"), Columns("I"))
        .Sort key1:=Columns("A"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        .Sort key1:=Columns("B"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    End With
End Function
```

Mock Data:

[image]

Comment: the `Key` for a `SortField` can only be one column. If you want to sort on multiple columns, create a helper column that concatenates the columns you wanted sorted and sort on that. Or you can add additional `SortFields` and sort them 1 by 1. So first `A` will sort, then `B`, then `C`.

Comment: I think I tried do individual ```SortFields``` but my concern is my A1 corresponds to a specific value in B1 and when I did the ```SortFields``` while it appeared to have worked it only Sort A Column by itself and B1 no longer matched it's original A1.

Comment: A less pretty way of doing sort is to pseudo-sort-field...  `range(col1,col2).sort key1:=columns(2)` then the next line is `range(col1,col2).sort key1:=columns(1)`, so col1 A-Z will still display A-Z in col2 for As, then for Bs, etc.

Comment: @Cyril So I tried  ```Range(A, B).Sort key1: Columns (2)``` and ```Range(A, B).Sort key1: Columns (1)``` but I got an error saying ```Compile error: Invalid use of property```

Comment: @RobertFarmer - sorting with formulas involved becomes very tricky. I think column B is a formula based on column A from what you are saying ...

Comment: @RobertFarmer Given Scott's feedback, I believe more information is needed about the source data.  Would you please edit your post to include mock-up of what is being worked through, if not the actual data?

Comment: Here's a Mock-Up of the data I'm trying to Sort. Each of the Columns are parts in a manufacturing line. and it goes by Dept-Cell-Operation-Part-Calc-Program-Date-Comment-Helper.

Comment: @RobertFarmer Just checked back on this and am seeing your comment; as you're the original poster (the only person who gets flagged for comments), you will need to @ tag people so they are aware you are responding to them.  Thanks for the mock data; just to be sure, the sorted columns do not contain formulae, yes?  Looks like Column F has a formula, but isn't part of the sort in your code.

Comment: @Cyril Column F has a simple Formula that is Just C+D it is necessary for a another part of my macro that removes items if they appear in another data-set I have.

Comment: @RobertFarmer Copy.  Then the listed expansion of my earlier comment as an answer should do the trick (I think you'll need to have your range be `Range(Columns("A"),Columns("I"))` for it to fit your model).  Let me know if you've had an issue since the answer was posted (I saw the compile error, so posted more clearly).

Comment: @Cyril I got around to implementing the code you suggested and I got a ```Sort method of range class failed``` and when I hit debug it highlighted the first ```.Sort key1:Columns("B"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes``` inside the code.

Comment: @RobertFarmer Odd, I tested that code; I am wondering if you don't have a merged cell in the column?

Comment: @Cyril on further inspection (sorry about the delay I haven't been at work for awhile) I see that I am building the i column in my macro rather than combining the data from the other columns using a formula. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Comment: @RobertFarmer does this mean that the question is no longer relevant or is that additional information?  If you are not having formulae involved, then sorting should work as intended in both these comments and the posted answer.

Comment: @Cyril That was additional information, I still am encountering the ```Run-time error '1004': Sort method of Range class failed``` with it highlighting ```.Sort Key1:=Columns("B"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes``` when I click debug.

Comment: @RobertFarmer Did you end up resolving your runtime error?  I was suspecting the dot notation may have caused an issue.

Comment: @Cyril I did once. I decided to just try and do the written out form of the sort like you provided below (I'm going to update the question as the error changed and I'm not sure if I encountered a new problem or if my Syntax is off.

Comment: @Cyril Apparently adding Worksheets('SheetName').Activate to the sheet made it work? I have some errors regarding subscripts out of range but that is for another post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RobertFarmer NP and glad it worked out.  In general, you shouldn't need `.Activate` (some specific cases require it); `With` statements using `.`notation help, and I just caught that in my example code, I didn't use `.Columns()` which could very well be the problem.  Every reference should be qualified... will edit that answer to reflect the importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing code from my comment as an answer so it is more readable

---

Using sort on individual columns across the same range will allow sorting xlAscending for each column, with the final sort providing the final A-Z:

Mock Data:

```
Col 1      Col 2
A          1
A          3
B          1
C          1
A          2
```

---

If you want Col1 to have primary hierarchy, it is sorted last, so:

```
With Range(Columns(1), Columns(2))
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(2), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    .Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

The above code is essentially:

```
.Range(.Columns(1), .Columns(2)).Sort key1:=.Columns(1), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=.Columns(2), order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

The single line approach has the highest priority as `key1`, second highest as `key2`, etc.

---

Output after code runs would be:

```
Col 1      Col 2
A          1
A          2
A          3
B          1
C          1
```

---

**Edit (after accept):**

I went back and added soem missing dot notation, found in the `key1:=.Columns(1)`... unqualified references will lead to problems.